# script to launch Stanford core nlp

Tags: 16.04, command-line, scripts

I normally launch Stanford CoreNLP server by opening terminal, navigating to folder where it saved and issuing the following command:

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

I tried to automate it. I created file `st_corenlp.sh` and put the following code inside this file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/home/Documents/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31"
sudo java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

I also went into file's properties and made it executable.

Now when I click it nothing happens. I also do not know how to run `st_corenlp.sh` from terminal to troubleshoot.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04

Any suggestions?

**Update**

I found out a way to run script from command line `bash -x st_corenlp.sh`,
but file is not running when I double-click on it. I double checked, it marked as executable.(check - Allow executing file as program)

Comment: Why `sudo` in the second case?

Comment: @steeldriver. I removed sudo, but it still does not work